# Getting parameters in label from a Gridview with SQLdatasource on a buttonclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I click a button in my gridview, the values of that particular row must be displayed in textlabels lblID, lblName, ...
I just don't have a clue how to do it.
This is the code of my sqldatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcProd" runat="server"  
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnDB %>"   
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnDB.ProviderName %>"   
SelectCommand="SELECT p.tProdID, p.tProdImage, p.tProdBeschrijving, m.tMerkNaam, m.tMerkImage,   p.tProdVerkoop FROM tblProducten AS p INNER JOIN tblMerken AS m ON p.tMerkID = m.tMerkID ORDER BY m.tMerkNaam">  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is a screenshot of the gridview I'm talking about.
[image: Here is a gridview screenshot]

When I press one of the buttons I would like e.g. the parameter ID displayed in lblID.

All help, hints and tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a `CommandName` (which is like "ShowDetails" or so) and a `CommandArgument` (which is the ID of the record) to the button. A click on the button will now trigger the grid's `RowCommand` event, passing you both `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` in `e`. Then fetch the record from your DB and populate your controls:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Foo2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowID") %>'
            CommandName="ShowDetails" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Command Handler");
}
```

Comment: Idd, that's best practise i guess. At some point, this method did not work for me, dont know why tho. Btw, can u specify multiple arguments here ? (and not as a ";" seperated string or so)

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot specify multiple arguments. I am annoyed at this pretty frequently too...

Comment: You can, using a ";" seperated string to pass multiple values. It's dirty in my opinion, but its possible.

Answer (score 1):

SO basicly this can be done on two ways:

1. Add a server-side click handler behind the button and update the label inside an UpdatePanel (this case we do not need a postback)
2. Add some javascript on the button's "OnClientClick" event to set this label... This method can be set in the GridView's bind method.

Hope this helps.